# which way for constructor is best?

Tags: c++, constructor

There are two ways construct a class:

```
  class Cell{
  public:
        Cell(int cellID, int nx);
        ~Cell();
  private:
        int cellID_;
        int nx;
  };
```

The first way:

```
  Cell::Cell(int cellID, int nx)
    : cellID_(cellID), nx_(nx){}
```

The second way :

```
  Cell::Cell(int cellID, int nx){init(cellID, nx)}

  void Cell::init(int cellID, int nx){
         cellID_ = cellID;
         nx_ = nx;
  }
```

Comment: Note that your code wont compiler as `nx_` is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Performance:

The first one is the best because it **initializes** the objects in true sense unlike second method which **assigns** the already initialized objects.

Note that there is a little overhead when you use the second method:

As you see there is an additional overhead of creation & assignment in the latter, which might be considerable for user defined classes.

```
Cost of Member Initialization = Object Construction 
Cost of Member Assignment = Object Construction + Assignment
```

In case of members which are in-built/POD data types there is no overhead but if the members are non POD types then the overhead is significant.

### Necessity:

Note that You will be forced to use the member initializer list in certain scenarios:

- Your class has a reference member
- Your class has a non static const member

Such members cannot be assigned to but they must be initialized in member initializer list.

---

Given the above as a practice the first method is always preferrable.

Answer (score 6):

The first is nearly always preferred. It's *necessary* for any members that are references, `const` or simply require initializers (i.e., can't be default constructed). In other cases, it can reduce extra work by directly initializing the member object instead of default-constructing, then assigning to it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In general, initialization lists are better. Check this C++ FAQ.

[Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html)

Except when you need the below functionality

[Can one constructor of a class call another constructor of the same class to initialize the this object?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-methods.html)

Comment: Your second link is no longer the case with C++11 delegating constructors.